# Can i create a real time chart with Pygal?

Tags: python, charts, html, bokeh, pygal

I created a Flask-SocketIO Python app. I'm looking for a way to embed into my webpage a real time chart.

When the user opens my webpage, he should see the chart updating with new data, but he should also be able to see the data from **before** the webpage was opened.

I found some Pygal/Flask examples, but none of them talks about real-time or updated charts. Would it be possible to do that. If it's not possible, could i alternatively use Bokeh?

Comment: I’ve used Chart.js in the past, very easy to use and great docs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **render_to_file('chart.svg')** for example, use **render_in_browser()**.

But it keeps generating a new html file, each time the graphic was updated.